# Cannot locate .keystore file for Android

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-keystore

I created a release key in the root directory of my ionic application using the command:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore android-release-key.keystore -alias myapp -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

I can then successfully sign my app using:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore android-release-key.keystore platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-release-unsigned.apk myapp
```

However, when I run:

```
keytool -v -list -keystore android-release-key.keystore
```

or

```
keytool -v -list -keystore android-release-key.keystore -alias myapp
```

I get the error:

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: android-release-key.keystore
java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: android-release-key.keystore
at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:745)
at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:343)
at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:336)
```

I am running this command from the root of my project directory, the same place I generated the key and use it to sign. What's going on here? How am I able to use the key to sign my app while also receiving an error that the file does not exist? My assumption is I'm searching for the .keystore file in the wrong place, but I can't seem to find it anywhere, yet it does exist. I'm on Mac by the way.

Comment: You have to put path of you keystore with this command.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know the path. I have no idea where it is saved. When I generated the key, I didn't specify a path.